Use Same SAP Domain from two different MC Accounts
We are planning to migrate existing MC Account A to new MC Account B.

MC Account A and B are in different stack.
MC Account A are now actively used, but will be shut down in near future.
MC Account B are about to newly implemented and we are going to submit new SAP form for this account.
I know that we cannot 'move' SAP settings from MC Account A to MC Account B cause they are in different stack.

My question here is that if we can use same SAP domain(from MC Account A) when submitting new SAP form for MC Account B. If yes, is there any considerations/limitations? (For example, we have to delete(?) the DNS settings already have done for MC Account A...)
